# Calculate total number of combinations of size k in array using recursion in Java?

Tags: java, recursion, combinations

I am attempting to write a recursive method that COUNTS the number of combinations of k size in an integer array.

I can easily do this for a known value k (e.g. 3) as so:

```
    int[] arr = {1,2,3,4};
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for(int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            for(int k = j+1; k < arr.length; k++) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I would like to be able to do this without a known k. I have found methods online that print the combinations using recursion, such as this one:
https://www.techiedelight.com/find-distinct-combinations-of-given-length/, but none that count them.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: You can just count them directly using n^k where n is the number of elements in the array and k is your desired size.

Comment: You don't need recursion - just compute `n!/k!(n-k)!`

Comment: If you **need** the solution to use recursion, then why not use the linked solution and increment a counter param instead of printing?

Comment: I know I don't have to but I would like to write a method that does use recursion

Comment: @arcadeblast77 I have attempted to do so but cannot figure out how to get it working unfortunately

Comment: I have figured it out - coding at 4am really takes a toll on the brain

Comment: Intuitively, the choice of r elements is equal to the combination of those choices which include the first value of your set and those that do not.  So `nCr = (n, r) => n < r ? 0 : r < 1 ? 1 : nCr(n - 1, r - 1) + nCr(n - 1, r)`

Answer (score 0):

Simple case of modifying the method linked.

```
public static int recur(int[] A, int i, int k)
{
    int count = 0;

    if (k == 0) {
        count++;
    }

    for (int j = i; j < A.length; j++) {
        count = count + recur(A, j + 1, k - 1);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I'd change `count++` to `return 1;`. While it doesn't affect the result, it saves you unnecessary recursive calls with negative values of k.

Comment: You can also stop passing in an array now and simply pass in the length, since the method doesn't do anything with the array's contents.